# need regex to extract groups from Unix id command

Tags: regex, linux, unix, grep

I need to extract the group names from Unix id command output. I tried but could not write the regex. Sample output of id command is:

```
uid=xxxxxx(amit) gid=xxxxxxx(xxxxxx) groups=xx(xxxx),xxxxxx(xxxxxx),xxxxx(xxxxx)
```

How do I extract the strings in brackets after `groups=` ?

Comment: More detail about what might be in the "xxxx"'s and "amit" please! (i.e. are they guaranteed to be strings?  Numbers?)

Comment: You mention that you tried - could you pls post your attempt and state where you got stuck? What part did you not get to work? What language are you using?

Comment: I am using Tcl but I can port the regex if in some other language. XXXXX can be string or number

Answer (score 1):

The **simplest** thing to if your version of `id` supports it is:

```
$ id -nG
group1 group2 group3
```

See `man id` for the availible options:

```
   -G, --groups
          print all group IDs
   -n, --name
          print a name instead of a number
```

If you really do want to know how to parse with a regular expression you could the following.

This regexp `(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\)(,|$))` will do the job, it use [positive-lookahead and look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match strings inside parenthesis followed by a comma or the end of the string. With `GNU grep`:

```
$ id | grep -Po '(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\)(,|$))'
group1
group2
group3
```

If you don't have `GNU grep` which support [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) then you could drop the look-arounds and filter with `sed`:

```
$ id | grep -Eo '\([^)]+\)(,|$)' | sed 's/[),(]//g'
group1
group2
group3
```

Comment: `(?=\),)` - don't you need to drop the `,` or it skips the last one?

Comment: @Dukeling not drop it as you will then also pick up the username but thanks for pointing that out. Fixed with alterantion for comma or end of string `(,|$)`.

Comment: Thanks a  lot for your quick help. I am looking for regex way of doing this as I have various other cases of this regex use.

Comment: @AmitGupta did you even read my answer!? I provided a couple of `regexp` solutions?

Comment: Thanks a lot. finally I got required regex as \([^)]+\)(?:,|$). many many thanks

Comment: @sudo_O: Do you mind stepping through your regexp '(?<=\()[^)]+(?=\)(,|$))' above and explaining it using the id output in the question?